# How does Stanford CoreNLP assign parentheses to phrases?

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have a question regarding how CoreNLP assigns parentheses to phrases en route to accumulating an overall sentence score.  The main question is the ORDER to which it calculates sentiment of phrases in a sentence.  Does anyone know what algorithm is used?  An example will clearly illustrate my question:

In my training model, the scale I am using is 0-4, where 0 is negative, 2 is neutral, and 4 is positive, so the following phrase is scored: (3 (1 lower) (2 (2 oil) (2 production)))
-Note: the reason for the jump to positive is we are predicting oil prices and lower oil production will lead to higher prices so a proper prediction of the price of oil increasing would need an overall positive sentiment.

Next, lets assume the following tweet was grabbed: "OPEC decides to lower oil production".  I assume the first thing CoreNLP does is assign each individual word a score.  In our training model, lower has a score of 1 and all other words are no scored so will receive a score of neutral.

The problem seems to stem from how CoreNLP decides to score phrases (groups of words).  If the first thing it did was score "oil production", then score "lower oil production", it would see we have an exact phrase match of "lower oil production" in our model and properly assign a score of 3.

However, what I'm guessing happens is this: first CoreNLP scores "OPEC decides", then "OPEC decides to", then "OPEC decides to lower", then "OPEC decides to lower oil", then OPEC decides to lower oil production".  In this instance, the phrase 'lower oil production' is never considered in a vacuum, because there are no phrases matching our training model, the individual word scores decide the overall sentiment and it gets a score of 1 due to "lower."

The only solution for this would be for someone to tell me the exact parentheses algorithm that CoreNLP uses to score phrases.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Stanford CoreNLP runs a constituency parser on the sentence.  Then it turns the constituency tree into a binary tree with TreeBinarizer.

This is the relevant class:

edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.TreeBinarizer

Here is a link to source code on GitHub:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/TreeBinarizer.java

Here is the source code of where that TreeBinarizer is set up:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/ParserAnnotator.java